# Can I use something like a control template in Xamarin to surround a new object?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My application has objects that are surrounded by this:

```
<StackLayout HeightRequest="49" BackgroundColor="Red" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0" >
    <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <!-- XAML here -->
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```

I would like to make it so that I don't need to enter the XAML on the 1st, 2nd, last and next to last lines each time.

Can I use something like a control template to avoid doing this and if so how would I use it?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a combination of `ContentPresenter` and `ControlTemplate` (as mentioned in the note on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-templates/creating))

> On a `ContentPage` (or `ContentView`), the `Content` property can be assigned and the `ControlTemplate` property can also be set. When this occurs, if the `ControlTemplate` contains a `ContentPresenter` instance, the content assigned to the `Content` property will be presented by the `ContentPresenter` within the `ControlTemplate`.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="DefaultTemplate">
    <StackLayout HeightRequest="49" BackgroundColor="Red"
                 Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0">
        <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <ContentPresenter /> <!-- This line is replaced by actual content -->
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
</ControlTemplate>
```

**Usage:**

```
<ContentView ControlTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultTemplate}">
    <!-- XAML here (basically the view that is to be surrounded by above layout) -->
    <Label TextColor="Yellow" Text="I represent the content" />
</ContentView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Xamarin also provide the Control Template functionalities in XAML.

Write a below code in App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="TealTemplate">
                <Grid>

                    <Label Text="Control Template Demo App"
                           TextColor="White"
                           VerticalOptions="Center" />
           </ControlTemplate>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

Call the template in side ContentPage

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="SimpleTheme.HomePage">
    <ContentView x:Name="contentView" Padding="0,20,0,0"
                 ControlTemplate="{StaticResource TealTemplate}">
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Label Text="Welcome to the app!" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            <Button Text="Change Theme" Clicked="OnButtonClicked" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: To make a good answer, can you use the XAML code in my question.  I think it will make it easier for others to follow. thanks

Comment: Yes it's same just replace the code as your needed-   <ControlTemplate x:Key="TealTemplate">
                <StackLayout HeightRequest="49" BackgroundColor="Red" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0" >
    <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <!-- XAML here -->
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>
           </ControlTemplate>